# Framer[CoffeeScript] - Cant access array in loop

Tags: coffeescript, framerjs

I can't access my array in a for loop - Why? Thanks in advance.

I want to play a state animation for my "PageDowns" elements.

[image]

Sorry, I couldn't paste the code, because CodeSample here didn't work for me.

Comment: without code sample its hard to test and help

Answer (score 0):

Got it on my own.

It was a scope problem. CoffeeScript is not easy to handle when it comes to arrays, loops and so on.

I had to write:

```
do(pageDown)
   PageDowns[i].animate "swipe"
```

Comment: You can read more about scope here: https://framer.com/getstarted/guides/programming/#scope